# How to make a bootable ISO file from a LiveOS USB?

Tags: boot, iso, livedvd

I've been trying to convert a bootable live OS 'multiboot' USB to ISO for burning to DVD.

The USB boots fine and was made using multibootUSB - which has a bootloader  with options to load various different Live OS - all work fine

Have tried to create an IMG file (which mounts fine with Ubuntu Disk Image mounter) but converting to an ISO:

```
mkisofs -o <iso output file name> <mountpoint>
```

results in an ISO that reports

> boot failed could not read from cdrom
>   boot failed could not read the boot disk
>   no bootable device

all this tested using QEMU and also Virtualbox

Anyone know how to create a bootable ISO file that will work...? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to convert your  'multiboot' USB to ISO for burning to DVD? Is the problem, that you cannot boot an old computer from USB? In that case maybe you can boot from a Plop CD and chainload to your working USB boot drive, [PLoP Boot Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#PLoP_Boot_Manager)

Comment: Example, create bootable DVD, any 'Linux OS' : `mkisofs -o [path-to]/new.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -J -R -V disks ./`

Comment: @sudodus - the nature of the OS means it that it should be on a non writeable medium such as DVDr

Comment: OK. Good luck and please share your solution when you are there :-)

Comment: @Knud Larsen - Thanks very much, would you use that command in a terminal with working directory as the USB top directory...? ALso: I think the multibootUSB sets up syslinux as boot loader, so the references in the command like isolinux.bin and boot.cat I'm guessing won't find corresponding files as far as I can see...? unless I misunderstand..? thanks again

Comment: Just an example, never done it with an "usb OS".

Answer (score 0):

The code given by Knud Larsen was useful to create a bootable DVD:

```
mkisofs -o [path-to]/new.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -J -R -V disks ./
```

I could boot into a menu, but I couldn't get the multi OS aspects to work, no matter how much I played around with isolinux/syslinux. In the end, [MultiCD](https://multicd.us/) was the best solution, works well, easy to use.